# Amazon URL scraping with XMLHTTP - Amazon blocking?

Tags: xmlhttprequest, screen-scraping

So if I use my browser to browse to a list of a product's ellers, for example:

https://www.amazon.co.uk/gp/offer-listing/B076C6769Z/ref=dp_olp_new?ie=UTF8&condition=new

I see a list of sellers.

BUT if I construct the same URL with VBA utilising XMLHTTP, Amazon returns a different page (generic page not related to the product). it's as if they've sussed that I'm not a person using a browser?

```
Dim XMLHTTP As Object, html As Object, objResult As Object
Set XMLHTTP = CreateObject("MSXML2.serverXMLHTTP")
url = "https://www.amazon.co.uk/gp/offer-listing/B002AVVO7K/ref=dp_olp_new? 
ie=UTF8&condition=new"
XMLHTTP.Open "GET", url, False
XMLHTTP.setRequestHeader "Content-Type", "text/xml"
XMLHTTP.setRequestHeader "User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; rv:25.0) 
Gecko/20100101 Firefox/25.0"
XMLHTTP.send
Set html = CreateObject("htmlfile")
html.body.innerHTML = XMLHTTP.responseText
Debug.Print XMLHTTP.responseText
```

Comment: It is not uncommon for web servers to deliver different content based on `User-Agent` and other HTTP headers that can be used to identify the type of client that is making the request. Since you are already using `XMLHTTP.setRequestHeader` to change your `User-Agent`, try playing with the string to mimic other web browsers until you find one that Amazon likes. Web browser useragent strings are readily available if you look around. You might also consider using an HTTPS proxy like Fiddler to compare what `XMLHTTP` is sending that might be different than what a real web browser sends.

Comment: Thanks for that - since Amazon responds fine when I manually use a browser, I suppose the obvious line of investigation would be to look at what's been sent to Amazon during a manual browsing session - are there any tools that trap the http requests that my PC browsers makes (when a human is using it!) ...if I can mimic that, then that ought to see me home & dry

Comment: Most modern browsers have their own built-in debuggers, which includes logging the HTTP messages they exchange with websites. Otherwise, try using [Fiddler](https://www.telerik.com/fiddler) or other debugging proxy, like I mentioned earlier.

Comment: Ok, I sussed how to view the header my manual browser makes, a bit overwhelmed at the amount of data!...